# How to prove that 0 is an element of $[0, \infty)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

For my homework, I have to prove that $[0, \infty)$ is an inductive set, and for a set to be inductive it has to contain $0$, and if $x$ is an element of $A$, then $x + 1$ must be an element of $A$.  I know that $0$ is an element of a because of the bracket, but I'm not exactly sure how to word it.  Do I know $0$ is an element because of the bracket (notation?) or is there some axiom that states a bracket means that the number is included in the set?  Thanks!

Comment: What class is this for? How much rigor and detail you need to provide probably depends on what class you're encountering this problem in.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut the class is called Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning.  Not a lot of detail is needed, just something like "by Thm xx" or "Axiom n"

Comment: How is the set $[0,\infty)$ defined?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen the theorem says: "[0, infinity) is an inductive set." and I have to prove that, if that counts as a definition

Comment: The set $[0,\infty)$ contains $0$ by its very definition: $$[0,\infty) = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid 0 \le x\}$$

Comment: @Mikeb No, you use the definition of $[0,\infty)$ to prove the theorem about it. Lee gives a definition, that is probably the one you’re supposed to use.

Comment: I suggest you (1) recheck your definition of "inductive", it doesn't make sense to call something inductive just for containing 0 and successors, and (2) state whether by $[0,\infty)$ you really mean the set of non-negative reals or, maybe, just the natural numbers ("non-negative integers"). The non-negative reals are not (usally) defined inductively.